# Multiple Trac projects

Tags: apache, project, trac

I'm building an integrated system where I am using **Trac** for wiki support running on **apache** webserver **2.2** with **mod_wsgi**.

I had this idea to have a folder structure that is not \Trac\Project but something a little more complex. I want my filesystem structure to be like:

```
-Trac  
 -SomeContext  
  -...  
   -Project1  
   -Project2    
 -SomeOtherContext  
  -...  
   -Project1  
   -Project2
```

I would like to access them with the url matching their filesystem location
**(ie: site.com\trac\SomeContext...\Project1)**
From what i understand about trac only the folders in \Trac\ are searched with no depth other than the root.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See recipes in 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac' for ideas of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply little modification is trac source code.

Comment: I'm using a windows system (WS2008) so can you give me some details on that?

Comment: Sorry i can't because i'm not scripting in python.

Comment: I'm no interested in scripting, i just want to know where i have to do the changes so i can have that functionality.  

I just want the search of trac instance to be done in all the subfolders not only on the folder specified in apache.